# copy data only cells to new worksheet but cycle through each worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to copy specific data from each sheet in a workbook and paste it on a different sheet one after another.  The number of rows is different on each sheet so i need to select only non-blank cells (and exclude formulas that result in blanks ie="").  I also need it to skip over 5 sheets as these do not have the info being requested. Sheets["SUMMARY TEMPLATE", "MILEAGE SUMMARY", "MILEAGE TRACKER", "ACTIVITY TRACKER", and "PBI DATA"]

Here is what I'd like to do:

- Loop through each worksheet except the 5 above.
  On each worksheet, copy all non-blank cells in range(B26:E38) and paste them on the "Activity Data" Sheet under the next blank cell.

I have tried to piece together a few different codes but none of them work together.

Please help!

I really appreciate any help, thanks!!

Here is what i have, it works when i run it on the activesheet but when i try to run it on all sheets (For each ws in Worksheets) I get a bunch of errors.

```
Sub a()
  Dim LR As Long, cell As Range, rng As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheets



  For Each ws In Worksheets
      With ws
      LR = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

      If ws.Name <> "SUMMARY TEMPLATE" And ws.Name <> "MILEAGE SUMMARY" And ws.Name <> "MILEAGE TRACKER" _
    And ws.Name <> "ACTIVITY TRACKER" And ws.Name <> "PBI DATA" Then
    For Each cell In .Range("B26:E26" & LR)
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = cell
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell
rng.Select
End With
Next ws
End If
End With
Next
Selection.Copy
Sheets("ACTIVITY TRACKER").Select
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you paste the errors you receive when you run the code on all worksheets?

Comment: If there is only 1 sheet it runs fine, if there is more than one i receive a run-time error '1004: Select method of Range class failed.

Comment: the code that is highlighted after i debug is:  rng.Select

Comment: while that may not be your problem: are you sure `.Range("B26:E26" & LR)` is not `.Range("B26:E" & LR)`?

Comment: I've tried both and get the same error with the same code highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

pls try this code (your code has to many `End If`, `End With` and `Next`):

```
Sub a()
  Dim LR As Long, cell As Range, rng As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
      If .Name <> "SUMMARY TEMPLATE" And .Name <> "MILEAGE SUMMARY" And .Name <> "MILEAGE TRACKER" _
                                          And .Name <> "ACTIVITY TRACKER" And .Name <> "PBI DATA" Then
        LR = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("B26:E" & LR)
          If cell.Value <> "" Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
              Set rng = cell
            Else
              Set rng = Union(rng, cell)
            End If
          End If
        Next cell
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
          rng.Copy
          Sheets("ACTIVITY TRACKER").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
          Set rng = Nothing
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Next ws
End Sub
```

still, you can not copy multiple ranges over different worksheets (you need to copy/paste it for each sheet). It will also error out for complex selectings (which cannot be copied in that way)

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this and i get a type mismatch error: For Each ws In Worksheets

Comment: `Dim ws As Worksheets` was the error... corrected it

Comment: the original error was *run-time error '1004: Select method of Range class failed.* but my code has no select... it is probably the copy which causes the error... simply try to select A1 and B2 (not the range, just that 2 cells) and then copy it... it is simply not allowed

Comment: am i correct that the cells from B to E stick together? so if you get B12 then you also need C12:E12?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  So if B is not empty then you will copy from B:E

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying? If yes, then let me know and I will comment the code.

```
Option Explicit

Dim ws As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Sub Sample()
    Dim rngToCopy As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim Myar As Variant, Ar

    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Activity Data")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case UCase(ws.Name)
        Case UCASE(wsOutput.Name), "SUMMARY TEMPLATE", "MILEAGE SUMMARY", _
        "MILEAGE TRACKER", "ACTIVITY TRACKER", "PBI DATA"
        Case Else
            lRow = GetLastRow

            For Each aCell In ws.Range("B26:E38")
                If aCell.Value <> "" Then
                    If rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngToCopy = aCell
                    Else
                        Set rngToCopy = Union(rngToCopy, aCell)
                    End If
                End If
            Next aCell
        End Select

        If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
            For Each Ar In rngToCopy
                lRow = GetLastRow
                Ar.Copy wsOutput.Range("A" & lRow)
            Next Ar
            Set rngToCopy = Nothing
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

Function GetLastRow() As Long
    With wsOutput
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If
    End With

    GetLastRow = lRow
End Function
```